# How to match field of different table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm using Django as backend, PostgresSQL as DB,  and HTML, CSS, and Javascript as frontend. I got stuck to **match the field** and `retrieve specific data` in Django.

```
class Motor(models.Model):
    .
    .
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    .
    .

class Drum(models.Model):
    .
    .
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    .
    .

class Cart(models.Model):
    .
    .
    motor = models.ForeignKey(Motor, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    drum = models.ForeignKey(Drum, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    .
    .
```

Now in the Above model, there is the `cart` Model which saves the data of the `Motor` Model or else saves the data of the `Drum` Model or both.

So for example If the user saves the data of the `Motor` Model in the `Cart` Model. The data which is saved in the `Cart` model should match the `code` field with model `Drum` and should filter the data accordingly.

So, I have done something like this.

**views.py**

```
def Drum(request):
    drum_filter = Drum.objects.filter(code__in=Cart.objects.all().values_list('code', flat = True))

    return render(request, 'list/drum.html', 
    {'drum_filter':drum_filter}
    )
```

But now the problem is: The `code` field in Cart goes as child table and my parent table is `Motor`.  something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "quantity": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
        },
        "motor": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "...",
            "title": "....",
            .
            .
            .
            "code": "DD1"
        },
        "drum": null
    }
]
```

]
Now I unable to match the table field in Django.

So lastly, the `code` field in the **Cart** model should match with the `code` field in the **Drum** model and if the user does not save any records in the **Cart** model, then whole `Drum` model records should filter. Just like this:

```
Drum = Drum.objects.all().order_by('price')
```

**Last but not least. Is it the right approach to this to filter specific data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you could filter as follows

```
def Drum(request):
drum_filter = Drum.objects.filter(code__in=Cart.objects.values_list('motor__code', flat = True))

return render(request, 'list/drum.html', 
{'drum_filter':drum_filter}
)
```

Second, you can check if cart list is empty

```
def Drum(request):

carts =  Cart.objects.values_list('motor__code', flat = True)
drum_filter = Drum.objects.filter(code__in=carts) if carts else Drum.objects.all().order_by('price')


return render(request, 'list/drum.html', 
{'drum_filter':drum_filter}
)
```

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: One more question if I have more then 3 model which is to be linked then how it will work

Comment: We can filter this way but I am not quite sure of your functional requirement. Could you elaborate how the code fields of motor and drum are related? why do you need to filter drum based on code of motor?

Comment: this all the models name are used in making Fan. So different fans have different motor and sizes of drum used so thats why i used that

Comment: one more question sir how to make it for more than 2 models. does we have to apply if condition

Comment: Suppose you have xyz model other than drum and motor models. you could could concat the code list. Something like qs1 = Cart.objects.values_list('motor__code', flat = True) , qs2 = Cart.objects.values_list('xyz__code', flat = True). Then codes = qs1.union(qs2, all=True).  Finally you can filter using codes. Is this what you mean by having more than 2 models?